# JGit Performance Issue

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jgit

I'm using Eclipse JGit, it is a wonderful plugin for Java developers to read files and content from a Git based repository. However, I have observed a performance issue of 22 secs+ to clone and open a repository using the APIs. Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Below is the code:

```
String localRepoFolder = "C:\\temp\\some-project";
Git localGit = Git.open(new File(localRepoFolder));
```

The above two statements take about 22 secs, not sure if there is solution for this problem or if there is a better plugin out there.

If anybody knows a solution for this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

-A

Comment: Do cloning and opening take 22 seconds or just opening? How big is the repository (.git folder)?

Comment: Please provide some numbers how big your repository is. For normal-sized repositories JGit is quite fast for me, at least I did not notice any big delays.